# Why does JProfiler log "ERROR: could not retransform class"?

Tags: jprofiler

I'm profiling (using instrumentation) a Java web app on Tomcat.  When I attach a JProfiler session it first goes through a period of `Retransforming Classes`.  During this period I am seeing numerous messages in the Tomcat log like these:

```
JProfiler> ERROR: could not retransform class Lcom/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool$HouseKeeper$$Lambda$36/1482601803; (62).
JProfiler> ERROR: could not retransform class Lcom/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool$HouseKeeper$$Lambda$35/545889432; (62).
JProfiler> ERROR: could not retransform class Lcom/sun/jersey/atom/rome/impl/provider/entity/AtomEntryProvider; (113).
JProfiler> ERROR: could not retransform class Lcom/sun/jersey/atom/rome/impl/provider/entity/AtomFeedProvider; (113).
```

What is the cause and implication of these errors?

I'm using:
Tomcat 7.0.55
Java 8
JProfiler 8.0.7

Comment: Do you use any other profiling or Java instrumentation agent? Instead of using quick attach, use the integration wizard (Session->Integration Wizards->New Server Integration) to modify the Tomcat start script. In that case, all transformations are done as the classes are loaded so no retransformations are necessary.

Comment: @Ingo, this error also occurs when I use the modified Tomcat script (generated through integration wizard).  The vast majority of the classes it cannot transform include "$$Lambda".  I'm wondering if it is somehow related to an issue JProfiler has with Java 8

Comment: Indeed, you need a newer version of JProfiler. You can update to 8.1.4 with the same license key.

Comment: @Ingo, upgrading fixed it for me.  If you want to change your comment to an Answer I will gladly accept.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The used version of JProfiler is too old and does not fully support Java 8. Updating to 8.1.4 will fix this issue.